# New driver/controller for Christmas tree LEDs

Tags: led, led-driver

I have a 600-LED Christmas tree. The controller went kaputt.

The tree consists of three sections with two groups of lights in each section. The LEDs themselves are a two-lead type RGB and have two wires connected to each lead.

[image]

Each section connects through two plugs in the center of the tree.

[image]

The wires from the plugs then come out of the center of the tree and connect to each group of lights in the section.

[image]

The original controller was powered by 24 VDC. If I apply 24 V directly to any group of lights nothing happens. Is there a controller/driver that would work to light the tree up and change the colors?

*additional info*

I have contacted the manufacturer and they were no help and offer no replacements. Two ICs in the controller are shorted out (getting very hot) and one of them is custom and not obtainable. Here are some pictures of the controller circuit boards

[image]
[image]

I painstakingly took one of the 6 strands of lights out. The beginning of the strand starts out like this with the positive from the plug going to the end of the strand and the negative from the plug going to the beginning of the strand.

[image]

So each of the strands in the tree is basically a loop. Also every 18 leds there is a section where there is only one wire between leds instead of the usual two as pictured

[image]

Comment: Without more information I doubt that we can answer this question. The best people to ask are the manufacturers of the tree. Will they sell you a replacement power supply? When you applied 24V to test, did you try it both ways round? Is it something as simple as a broken wire coming out of the power supply?

Comment: Gonna have to take the controller apart and do some analysis to figure out how the lights were driven. Post pics of the insides.

Comment: I added more pics and info.

Comment: Are your LEDs like this? https://youtu.be/WLXnCaXX7w4

Comment: Do the LED chains connect to the controller at both ends or just one end?

Comment: _"every 18 leds there is a section where there is only one wire between leds instead of the usual two"_ - how many LEDs are in the entire strand?

Comment: My guess is that the LEDs are all in parallel and that by applying 24v to the strings you fried the IC on their anvils. Look up the follow-up video by Julian on how they change color: https://youtu.be/gxdgRHmOuIo

Comment: The leds are still functional. I tested them individually and they still work. In the particular strand I removed there was 90 led's altogether. And I had previously watched the video by Julian but didn't know what controller would be good for sending pulses. The leds connect at just one end. Like the picture shows there is just one plug on the strand.

Comment: So, you might have a series of five chunks of 18 LEDs in parallel (5x18=90). How did you test the single LED? Fixed voltage across it? Have you tried manually 'pulsing' it to see if by chance you get a different color?

Comment: What would be the correct way to apply voltage if the leds are in parallel? I was able to test the leds by plugging them into the old controller where a part of it is still working. Pulsing them didn't change anything.

Comment: Also if they were in parallel wouldn't the voltage be 24v at each led? When the controller was still working I measured much less then that at a couple different Leds around 4 to 6 volts.

Comment: If the LEDs are the same shown by Julian, about 5v would be right. Your 5 series of nearly 5v chunks would require a total of 24-25V. But if the LEDs have the same ic you need to give small pulses to set the color, otherwise they won't light up. You can use a fixed power supply at 24v, and then a couple of MOSFETs to create a cmos inverter that can be controlled by the Arduino following Julian's example. (Worth a shot, and if you have an oscilloscope and a floating power source you could look at what makes the led light up)